# Is logarithmic additive approximation to bin covering possible?

Tags: approximation-algorithms, packing, covering-problems

For the bin packing problem, the [Karmarkar-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karmarkar-Karp_bin_packing_algorithms) (1982) finds in polynomial time a packing with $OPT+O(\log^2(OPT))$ bins, and this was recently improved by Hoberg and Rothvoss (2017) to $OPT+O(\log(OPT))$.

The [bin covering problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_covering_problem) is a dual problem, in which the goal is to *maximize* the number of bins with total size *above* a threshold. One could expect to have an algorithm that finds in polynomial time a covering with $OPT-O(\log^2(OPT))$ bins, or $OPT-O(\log(OPT))$ bins. But so far, the closest approximation algorithm I could find is by Jansen and Solis-Oba (2002), which finds a covering with  $(1-\epsilon)OPT-O(1/\epsilon^3)$ bins; with $\epsilon=OPT^{-1/4}$ this gives $OPT-O(OPT^{3/4})$, which is quite far away.

Questions:

- Is there a polynomial-time algorithm for bin covering, that attains a better additive gap than $OPT-O(OPT^{3/4})$? (I did not find in Google Scholar, but perhaps I missed).
- From reading the paper of Jansen and Solis-Oba, it seems that the main obstacle for improving the approximation for bin covering is the need to handle small items, which is apparently much harder in bin covering than in bin packing. If we are given an instance with no small items (e.g. the size of all items is at least $1/d$ of the capacity, for some constant $d$), is it possible to cover $OPT-O(\log^2(OPT))$ bins using the Karmarkar-Karp algorithm? Or $OPT-O(\log(OPT))$ bins using the Hoberg-Rothvoss algorithm?